# Getting System.NullReferenceException while trying to use docker-dotnet-sonarscanner

Tags: docker, sonarqube, containers

I'm trying to check the code coverage locally using using [docker-dotnet-sonarscanner](https://github.com/burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner).

My steps until now:

1. Run the container with the Sonarqube, like so:

   `docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube`
2. Now, I'm trying to execute the analyze, inside my project folder, I ran:

   `docker run --name dotnet-scanner -it --rm -v $(pwd) \
   -e PROJECT_KEY=ConsoleApplication1 \
   -e PROJECT_NAME=ConsoleApplication1 \
   -e PROJECT_VERSION=1.0 \
   -e HOST=my_ip_address:9000 \
   -e LOGIN_KEY=the_key_I_got_on_local_Server\
   burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner`

But I get the following output:

> 19:02:22.429  Failed to request and parse '172.20.61.69:9000/api/server/version': An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.WebClientDownloader+PersistentUserAgentWebClient.GetWebRequest (System.Uri address) [0x00014] in :0
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x0000d] in :0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That's powershell, not C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer, I should pass my ip address with a prefix of `http`, like so:

```
docker run --name dotnet-scanner -it --rm -v $(pwd) \
-e PROJECT_KEY=ConsoleApplication1 \
-e PROJECT_NAME=ConsoleApplication1 \
-e PROJECT_VERSION=1.0 \
-e HOST=http://my_ip_address:9000 \
-e LOGIN_KEY=the_key_I_got_on_local_Server\
burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner
```